# How to link a large number of items at one time in mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

For example:

There are 10,000 items in a list and the user needs to be able to select a portion of these based on whatever criteria, and then put them into a group. So as the user, I filter the list of these 10,000 items based on whatever, hit select all and then click "Group".

I'm trying to come up with the most efficient method of linking these all together.

If I have item_table and group_table and then group_has_item, I'd effectively have to INSERT 1,000 rows at one time into the group_has_item table. Is there an efficient way to do this? Or is there a better schema? The only requirement is that these items have to be able to be tied to multiple groups at once.

Comment: So are these criteria fixed or can the user add arbitrary items to a grooup?

Comment: Can a single item belong to multiple groups?

Comment: A single item can belong to multiple groups and the criteria are not fixed. Basically it's allowing the user to create lists of items with certain criteria.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance of 1000s of INSERTs, you can reduce the load by running prepared statements with params or joining several inserts in one query,

Comment: andr - can you give me an example of a "prepared statement with params" that would work in this situation? Is the performance of a 1000 joined inserts that much better than 1000 separate insert statements if they're sent in the same batch?

Comment: What I would recommend is getting the thing working and then, if it happens to be a bit sluggish, ask about improvement. You'll often be surprised with what you can get away with.

Answer (score 2):

> If I have item_table and group_table and then group_has_item, I'd effectively have to INSERT 1,000 rows at one time into the group_has_item table. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Yes - what you describe is the proper way to associate the records.
It's called a many-to-many relationship, and uses a table for holding these relationships.  Some call the table linking the two entities map, lookup, xref... I've forgotten some of the synonyms.

Comment: Just to add to that, performance is not an issue here if you select your data types and indexes appropriately.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I described a standard a many to many relationship - but I'm wondering if there's a better way since I'm trying to establish these relationships with huge numbers of things at random.

Comment: Performance isn't an issue with issuing 1000 insert statements at once?

Comment: @Chris: many-to-many is the best solution if you want to perform any sort of relational integrity, reporting...  Honestly, how often do you see 1,000 inserts happening?

Comment: Agreed - you can work on the performance issues, but this is the right way to represent the relationships.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: If I enable this functionality, a lot more often than I'd like. But I did just think of a better way to do it. When they create the group, I'll only have it store the filter conditions plus additions or exceptions. That should reduce the db work quite a bit.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, but what about when you want to find group/item associations for only two groups?  I can't stress how much you risk hamstringing your application by storing denormalized data.  Ultimately, it's your app and your decision...